# How do I use my ownCloud Caldav with the Calendar Application?

Tags: calendar

Any idea? There is no box for my password and I get HTTP-Error 8 (Message Corrupt). I used https://mysite.com/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/ and as username me@mysite.com.

Answer (score 1):

You will be asked for password while connecting to the caldav, and you can store the passwd for later.

Try to use username without "@mysite.com", it should work (it did for me).

BR,

l.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old thread but for someone who is looking for more answers as I did:
I have self hosting Nextcloud instance on Apache using Raspberry Pi 3 and I have generated self-signed certificate for it. The eOS calendar refused to connect at all. I had to generate the certificate through Let’s Encrypt and now it’s working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

But as far as I know you have to add each individual calender separately.
In OwnCloud / NextCloud each individual calendar has a link button, maybe behind a submenu (3 dots). The link that appears is the link you use as URL. Then when you also include the correct username and press Create calendar it should ask for your password.

I'm sure I've read this on a OwnCloud page somewhere, but couldn't find it anymore.